# unable to understand ruby method call

Tags: ruby

I have a method definition in ruby file (get_java_opts)-
Then one more method calls this "get_java_opts" method with below syntax-
What is this line doing?-

```
get_java_opts ? my_java_opts = get_java_opts : my_java_opts = @java_opts
```

Code from my ruby file-

```
def start
  appdir = "#{@rootdir}/mydir"
  wo_prop = "#{@rootdir}/app.properties"
  get_java_opts ? my_java_opts = get_java_opts : my_java_opts = @java_opts
```

Method definition-

```
def get_java_opts
  yml = "#{@rootdir}/#{@test}.yaml"
  y = YAML.load_file(yml) if File.exists?(yml)
  java_opts = y[@app]['java_opts'] rescue "No YAML found"
end
```

Comment: and can be simplified as `my_java_opts = get_java_opts || @java_opts`

Comment: Are you aware that your code will eventually assign the string `"No YAML found"` to `my_java_opts`?

Answer (score 3):

It is called "ternary operator". This line

```
get_java_opts ? my_java_opts = get_java_opts : my_java_opts = @java_opts
```

is equivalent to this

```
if get_java_opts
  my_java_opts = get_java_opts
else
  my_java_opts = @java_opts
end
```

Comment: ...and should be written as `my_java_opts = get_java_opts ? get_java_opts : @java_opts` to DRY due to ternary returns a value. (Or even better `my_java_opts = get_java_opts || @java_opts` :)

Comment: @mudasobwa: did you ninja-change your comment or I didn't see the last part (with the `||`) the first time? :)

Comment: ninja-change (I am selling a 32 hrs training course on how-to-do-it for $799 only.)

Answer (score 0):

The `Ternary Operator` syntax is like `condition ? true : false`
Lets understand its working using `get_java_opts ? my_java_opts = get_java_opts : my_java_opts = @java_opts` as example
Let us divide our expression in parts `PART A ? PART B : PART C`
Now ,
in `PART A` you've `get_java_opts`,
in `PART B` you've `my_java_opts = get_java_opts`, and
in `PART C` you've `my_java_opts = @java_opts`
So Now,
let's assume your `PART A` is returning either `true` or `false`.
If `PART A` return `true` then then the `PART B` will execute which is `my_java_opts = get_java_opts`
and if `PART A` return `false` then the `PART C` will execute which is `my_java_opts = @java_opts`.